# I need to use intermediate Array in loop

Tags: objective-c, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a basic question. I need to use intemediate array in loop. This is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *interArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
NSMutableArray *finalyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger a;
for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
{    [interArray removeAllObjects];
     for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
     {
     a = [array ObjectAtInde:i];  // this is existing array
     [interArray addObject:a];
     }
    [finalyArray addObject:interArray];
}
```

but when i delete objects in intermediate array I get empty Arrays in finaly Array. How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: What do you want `finalyArray` to look like WRT inputs?

Comment: I to get finalyArray where objects are Arrays also. Actually it doesn't metter. I need to understand how to work with intermediate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it won't work as you expect is because `interArray` is a reference to an object which you empty and fill in the loop and then add to the `finalyArray`, however you are adding the same intermediate array each time.

What you want to do it create a new intermediate array *within* the loop and therefore each intermediate array will be a separate object:

```
NSMutableArray *finalyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger a;
for(int j=0; j<5; j++)
{
     NSMutableArray *interArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];
     for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
     {
     a = [array ObjectAtIndex:i];  // this is existing array
     [interArray addObject:a];
     }
    [finalyArray addObject:interArray];
}
```

(Note this code won't work anyway as you cannot store `NSInteger` in a collection class without first wrapping it in a `NSNumber` object).

Comment: … and the whole inner part of the `for` loop can thus be optimized into this: `[finalyArray addObject:@[ array[0], array[1] ]];` (I'm assuming that `array` really is an `NSArray`; whether you actually want the same first two items of `array` over and over again, I don't know but that's what the original code did). If you need `NSMutableArray` instances, it's `[finalyArray addObject:[@[ array[0], array[1] ] mutableCopy]];`